# Can not register new user Spring Boot 1.x.x with thymelea, jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I can not register a new user. It's not about my html file because I changed other form but still not working. Then I decided to write a restAPI first but still same result.

It returns no error but it doesn't add any new record in my db. I checked all name of field in db or html file or entity but all of them have right name. Why I can't add a new one?

My Entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    private String password;
```

Application.properties

```java
#spring-hibernate for mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_my_project?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
#log
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.demo.springmvc=DEBUG
```

UserService

```java
   public String registerNewUser(User user) {
        try {
            // check existed user
            if(findUserByUsername(user.getUserName()) != null) {
                return "Existed_Username";
            }

            if(findUserByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
                return "Existed_Email";
            }

            // hash pass
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            user.setCreatedDate(new Date());

            // save user
            userRepository.save(user);

            // insert new role
            UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
            userRole.setRoleID(RoleConstant.Role_User);
            userRole.setUserID(user.getId());

            userRoleRepository.save(userRole);

            return "Success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I tried on restAPI first but not working, no record added?

```java
@RestController
public class UserAPIController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/register")
    public String registerNewUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserName(userDTO.getUsername());
            user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(userDTO.getPassword());
            userService.registerNewUser(user);
            return "success";
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Transactional` on your `registerNewUser` method. There are two save methods in it and they need to run as a transaction.  Don't persist in your controller. It is bad practice.